# WaitForSeconds functions in cpp

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a function in C++ that delays the function it is running in for an amount of time, similar to WaitForSeconds in C#? I am aware of Sleep, but that pauses the entire program, I only want to pause a single function.

Comment: `std::this_thread::sleep_for()`

Comment: `Sleep` and `sleep_for` both pause the current thread. What do you mean by "pausing a single function"?

Comment: ***but that pauses the entire program*** This would appear to happen if the current thread is the GUI thread. I mean if you execute a function in the GUI thread and that function sleeps then the GUI will be frozen while the function is sleeping. This assumes your GUI operates on a single thread.

Comment: I suspect the OP is really asking scheduling a C++ coroutine.  It's a new feature of C++ 20.  Read more here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines

Comment: Aravash - does your application have the concept of a message pump like a GUI app normally has?  That enables a lot of options if you do,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your programs architecture, if you let the function run on its own thread then yes you can use std::this_thread::sleep_for function to pause that function without affecting the whole program e.g.

```
void mythread()
{
  int sum = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    sum += i;
  }
  return sum;
}

int main()
{
  std::future<int> result = new std::async(mythread);
  // do something else
  // ...
  result.get();
}
```